# What is $\{u+u^p: u\in F\}$ in the finite field $F_{p^n}$?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$ (including the case $p=2$). I know that $F^p:=\{u^p: u\in F\}=F$, because all finite fields are perfect. But what holds for the sets $\{u+u^p: u\in F \}$, $\{u+u^p+u^{p^2}: u\in F\}$ and so on, in general?  I can only see that these are subgroups of $(F,+)$.

I would be very surprised if it were the case that $\{u+u^p+u^{p^2}+\ldots +u^{p^k}: u\in F \}=F$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$, but I don't see how to so that this is not the case in general.

Comment: There is no particular context really. Just trying to get intuition about the structure of finite fields and this question came to mind.

Comment: Well, if $n$ is even or $p=2$, for $a = u + u^p$, then $a$ is a root of $a - a^p + a^{p^2} - a^{p^3} + \cdots + (-1)^{n-1} a^{p^{n-1}}$.  And I think by a counting argument (including the fact that all the roots are distinct because the polynomial has derivative 1), every such root $a$ should have some $u \in F$.  I'm not sure if that's the sort of answer you're looking for.

Comment: @DanielSchepler So, your argument shows that in this case there are at most $p^{n-1}$ elements in $\{u+u^p: u\in F\}$? Interesting.

Comment: Computationally, $\{u+u^p\colon u\in F\} = F$ for lots of finite fields $F$ of odd characteristic, while it's a subgroup of index $2$ for lots of finite fields of even characteristic.

Comment: On the other hand, if $n=1$ and $p>2$, then $u + u^p = 2u$ so $\{ u + u^p \mid u \in F \} = F$.

Comment: @GregMartin And I presume there is a case when it has index $p$ for $p\neq 2$?

Comment: Have you tried considering Primitive roots? It might help.

Comment: It may be instructive to figure out the structure of $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ as an $\Bbb F_p[C_n]$-module. Presumably it matters if $p\mid n$ or not.

Comment: @User I did not find one in my calculations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linear algebra to the rescue!

Let $K=\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ be the finite field of cardinality $p^n$, $p=\mathrm{char} K$, a prime number. The first and most obvious observation is that
$$T:K\to K, u\mapsto u+u^p$$
is a linear transformation over the prime field $\Bbb{F}_p$. This is because raising to $p$th power is additive (by Freshman's dream), and maps the elements of the prime field to themselves (by Little Fermat). As $T$ is a polynomial of degree $p$, it has at most $p$ zeros in the field $K$. We can thus conclude that $\mathrm{Ker}(T)$ has dimension zero or one. Hence, by rank-nullity, $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ is either all of $K$ or a subspace of codimension one.  The next task is to determine, which case occurs when.

If $u\in K^*$ is in the kernel, then $u^p=-u$. In other words, the Frobenius automorphism $F:K\to K, x\mapsto x^p$, has $-1$ as an eigenvalue. Because $F^n$ is the identity on all of $K$, we arrive at the parity condition
$$u=F^n(u)=(-1)^nu$$
implying that $(-1)^n=1$.

This means that for $T$ to have a non-trivial kernel, we must either have $1=-1$ (i.e. $p=2$) or $2\mid n$. It is easy to see that this necessary condition is also sufficient:

- If $p=2$, then $1_K\in\mathrm{Ker}(T)$.
- If $p>2$ and $2\mid n$, then the mapping $\Phi:x\mapsto x^{p-1}$ is a homomorphism from the cyclic group $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}^*\subseteq K^*$ of order $p^2-1$ to itself. Therefore the image $S$ of $\Phi$ consists of the roots of unity of order $(p^2-1)/(p-1)=p+1$. As $p+1$ is an even number, it follows that $-1\in S$. Therefore there exists an element $z\in\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ such that $z^{p-1}=-1$. Consequently $z^p=-z$, and $z$ is a non-zero element in $\mathrm{Ker}(T)$. We can reach the same conclusion by using the fact that the minimal polynomial of the Frobenius automorphism of $K$ is $x^n-1$, hence the possible eigenvalue $\lambda=-1$ occurs whenever $2\mid n$.

**Conclusion.** If $p>2$ and $2\nmid n$, then $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ is all of $K$, and otherwise it is a codimension one subspace (over the prime field).

---

Something more can be said about the image of $T$ in those cases where $T$ is not onto.

- When $p=2$ it follows easily that $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ is exactly the
  kernel of the absolute trace $tr:K\to\Bbb{F}_2$,
  $$tr(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}F^j(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}=x^{2^j}.$$ This is
  because obviously $tr(x)=tr(x^2)$ for all $x\in\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$
- When $p>2$, $2\mid n$, we can similarly describe the image of $T$ as the kernel of a linear combination of the powers of Frobenius, this time with alternating signs. See Daniel Schepler's comment under main.

---

More generally, studying the image of
$$
T_k:K\to K, u\mapsto u+u^p+u^{p^2}+\cdots+u^{p^k}
$$
instead of $T=T_1$, we can do the following. First we think of $T_k$ as an $\Bbb{F}_p$-linear mapping from an algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ to itself. As an endotransformation of $\overline{K}$ we see that the kernel of $T_k$ consists of the trace zero elements of the finite field $L=\Bbb{F}_{p^{k+1}}\subset \overline{K}$. Therefore the kernel of the restriction of $T_k$ to the field $K$ must lie in the intersection $L\cap K$.

- If $L\cap K$ is a proper extension field of the prime field, then the kernel of $T_k$ is automatically non-trivial. This is because the kernel of the extended version of $T_k$ is a codimension one subspace of $L$. Observe that $L\cap K$ is non-trivial if and only if $\gcd(k+1,n)>1$.
- If $L\cap K=\Bbb{F}_p$ is the prime field, that is, if $\gcd(k+1,n)=1$, then the answer depends on whether the elements of the prime field belong to the kernel of the trace map of $L$. Because the Frobenius fixes the elements of the prime field, this happens if and only if $p\mid k+1$.

**General conclusion.** The mapping $T_k:K\to K$ is onto, unless either $p\mid k+1$ or $\gcd(k+1,n)>1$.

Observe that the earlier conclusion is just the special case $k=1$.

---

With more general sums of powers of Frobenius the situation becomes more complicated. A general tool is to think of the algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ as an $\Bbb{F}_p[\tau]$-module (a simple polynomial ring, so among other things a Euclidean domain). We achieve this by letting the indeterminate $\tau$ act via Frobenius. So if $a(\tau)=\sum_i a_i\tau^i\in\Bbb{F}_p[\tau]$ and $x\in\overline{K}$ are arbitrary, we define
$$
a(\tau)\cdot x=\sum_i a_ix^{p^i}.
$$
The analogous question is then to fix a polynomial $a(\tau)$ and study the action of $a(\tau)$ on various finite subfields of $\overline{K}$. Above we got the transformation $T_k$ with the choice $a(\tau)=1+\tau+\cdots+\tau^k$. Anyway, if $a(\tau)$ has a non-zero constant term, then there exists an integer $m$ such that $a(\tau)\mid \tau^m-1$. It follows that all $a(\tau)$-torsion then lies in the field $E=\Bbb{F}_{p^m}$, and we can make deductions in certain cases as above. Of course, in the general case it is more difficult to identify the exact $a(\tau)$-torsion elements inside $E$.

Comment: In the general case the codimension of the image of $T_k$ may be quite large, depending on the key parameter $\gcd(k+1,n)$.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer Jyrki!

Comment: Impressive answer as always!